# using cython to generate a unix timestamp

Tags: python, cython, unix-timestamp, python-datetime

If you have every integer in memory to construct a datetime object, is there a better way than the following.

```
atoi(datetime(year,month,day,hour,minute,second).stftime("%s"))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`time.mktime()`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/time.html#time.mktime) together with [`datetime.timetuple()`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timetuple):

```
dt = datetime.datetime(year, month, day, hour, minute, second)
unix_time = time.mktime(dt.timetuple())
```

---

Or, if you don't need the `datetime` object, you can construct a 9-tuple compatible with [`time.struct_time`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/time.html#time.struct_time) and pass it directly to `mktime()`:

```
time_tuple = (year, month, day, hour, minute, second, day_of_week, day_in_year, dst)
unix_time = time.mktime(time_tuple)
```

Note that [`time.mktime()` does not take into account `day_of_week` and `day_in_year`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mktime), so feel free to set them to `-1`.

You may also set `dst` to `-1`, indicating that `mktime` should automatically determine whether DST is in effect.

---

Using Cython, you can also construct a `struct tm` and pass it directly to [`mktime(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mktime):

```
from libc.time cimport tm, mktime

cdef tm time_tuple = {
    'tm_sec': second,
    'tm_min': minute,
    'tm_hour': hour,
    'tm_mday': day,
    'tm_mon': month - 1,
    'tm_year': year - 1900,
    'tm_wday': day_of_week,
    'tm_yday': day_in_year,
    'tm_isdst': dst,
    'tm_zone': NULL,
    'tm_gmtoff': 0,
}
unix_time = mktime(&time_tuple)
```

This is exactly [what happens behind the scenes when you call `time.mktime()`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/25d78aa1ec21/Modules/timemodule.c#l407) in Python.

Again, `tm_wday`/`day_of_week` and `tm_yday`/`day_in_year` are ignored and `dst` may be `-1`.

Comment: Thank you, the cython one was exactly what i needed.